# How can I post arrays of Schemas inside a Schema?

Tags: node.js, express, mongoose

I have two schemas, one is called `position` other one is called `path`. Basically, I want path `schema` to hold an array of `position` schemas.

So first, this is my `position` schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var positionSchema = new Schema({
    position : {
        x : Number,
        y : Number
    },
    orientation : {
        x : Number
    }
});

var Position = mongoose.model('Position', positionSchema);
module.exports = Position
```

Simple one, just holds some float numbers. Then, this is my `path` schema, it is like a father to `position` schema:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var Position = require('./position');

var pathSchema = new Schema({
    path : [{type: Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Position'}]
});

module.exports = mongoose.model("Path", pathSchema);
```

So now, I want to POST some arrays of positions to path schema using Postman and code for that looks like this:

```
router.post("/", (req,res,next)=>{
    const _path = new Path({
        path : req.body.path
    })
    .save()
    .then(docs => {
        const response = {
            status: 201,
            message: "Path has been added succesfully",
            path_ID: docs.path_id,
            path : docs.path
        };
        res.status(201).json(response);
    })
    .catch(err => {
        res.status(500).json({
            message: err
        });
    });
});
```

But when I use this example in Postman:

```
{"path" : [
    {"position" : { "x": "1111", "y" : "2222"}, "orientation" : { "x":"0"} },
{"position" : { "x": "1111", "y" : "2222"}, "orientation" : { "x":"0"} }
]}
```

I get an error:

```
 {
    "message": {
        "errors": {
            "path": {
                "message": "Cast to Array failed for value \"[ { position: { x: '1111', y: '2222' }, orientation: { x: '0' } },\n  { position: { x: '1111', y: '2222' }, orientation: { x: '0' } } ]\" at path \"path\"",
                "name": "CastError",
                "stringValue": "\"[ { position: { x: '1111', y: '2222' }, orientation: { x: '0' } },\n  { position: { x: '1111', y: '2222' }, orientation: { x: '0' } } ]\"",
                "kind": "Array",
                "value": [
                    {
                        "position": {
                            "x": "1111",
                            "y": "2222"
                        },
                        "orientation": {
                            "x": "0"
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "position": {
                            "x": "1111",
                            "y": "2222"
                        },
                        "orientation": {
                            "x": "0"
                        }
                    }
                ],
                "path": "path",
                "reason": {
                    "message": "Cast to ObjectId failed for value \"{ position: { x: '1111', y: '2222' }, orientation: { x: '0' } }\" at path \"path\"",
                    "name": "CastError",
                    "stringValue": "\"{ position: { x: '1111', y: '2222' }, orientation: { x: '0' } }\"",
                    "kind": "ObjectId",
                    "value": {
                        "position": {
                            "x": "1111",
                            "y": "2222"
                        },
                        "orientation": {
                            "x": "0"
                        }
                    },
                    "path": "path"
                }
            }
        },
        "_message": "Path validation failed",
        "message": "Path validation failed: path: Cast to Array failed for value \"[ { position: { x: '1111', y: '2222' }, orientation: { x: '0' } },\n  { position: { x: '1111', y: '2222' }, orientation: { x: '0' } } ]\" at path \"path\"",
        "name": "ValidationError"
    }
}
```

So I guess it is something with my post method as my server does not recognize the post message correctly and awaits for something else.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: `Unexpected token " in JSON at position 0` the `"` is **unexpected** because you are not posting **valid JSON**. Hope that makes the error message much clearer.

Comment: Your JSON is not valid. Probably, you are missing opening and closing brackets, `{"key": "value"}`.

Comment: there is some error from sending data from your frontend. try inspect element feature of browser and check/compare json of postman and frontend

Comment: can you please share what json you have sent when you got this error

Comment: @Vipul I have updated the code with the JSON I have sent for this particular error :)

Answer (score 0):

`path` inside `pathSchema` is an array of references to `Position` documents. That means that `path` has to store an array of `ObjectId` while you are trying to assign an array of objects to it. You have to save `Position`'s first and after that push their `_id` values to `path` array:

```
router.post("/", (req,res,next)=>{
    const savePositions = req.body.path.map(position => {          // create promises that save Position documents
        return new Position(position).save();
    });

    Promise.all(savePositions)                                     // run all save promises in parallel
      .then(positions => positions.map(position => position._id))  // get an array of ids of saved documents
      .then(positionsIds => new Path({ path: positionsIds }).save())
      .then(savedPath => {
        // do the job with saved Path
      })
      .catch(err => {
        // handle the error
    });
});
```